# In what moment does variable declaration occur?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration, var, let

As I understand it, all code is executed in 2 stages: initial code scan (compilation) and code execution. However, it's still not entirely clear to me at what stage the declaration of variables occurs.

**On the one hand,** it specifies [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-execution-context-and-execution-stack-in-javascript-1c9ea8642dd0#:%7E:text=Let%E2%80%99s%20look%20at%20some%20example%20to%20understand%20the%20above%20concepts%3A) that an execution context is created before executing the JavaScript code. And in the same article, below is an example of a schematic representation of an execution context:

```js
let a = 20;
const b = 30;
var c;
function multiply(e, f) {
 var g = 20;
 return e * f * g;
}
c = multiply(20, 30);
console.log(c);


//Схематичное представление контекста выполнения для этого кода будет выглядеть так:
// GlobalExectionContext = {
//   ThisBinding: <Global Object>,
//   LexicalEnvironment: {
//     EnvironmentRecord: {
//       Type: "Object",
//       // Данные о привязках для идентификаторов
//       a: < uninitialized >,
//       b: < uninitialized >,
//       multiply: < func >
//     }
//     outer: <null>
//   },
//   VariableEnvironment: {
//     EnvironmentRecord: {
//       Type: "Object",
//       // Данные о привязках для идентификаторов
//       c: undefined,
//     }
//     outer: <null>
//   }
// }
// FunctionExectionContext = {
 
//   ThisBinding: <Global Object>,
//   LexicalEnvironment: {
//     EnvironmentRecord: {
//       Type: "Declarative",
//       // Данные о привязках для идентификаторов
//       Arguments: {0: 20, 1: 30, length: 2},
//     },
//     outer: <GlobalLexicalEnvironment>
//   },
// VariableEnvironment: {
//     EnvironmentRecord: {
//       Type: "Declarative",
//       // Данные о привязках для идентификаторов
//       g: undefined
//     },
//     outer: <GlobalLexicalEnvironment>
//   }
// }
```

That is, as I understand it, during the initial scan of the code, variables are declared. For variables declared with `let` and `const`, it writes `uninitialized` - that is, these variables are declared, but not yet initialized. Variables declared with `var` are immediately initialized with `undefined`.

**On the other hand,** there is TDZ (temporal dead zone). [Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-the-temporal-dead-zone/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20what%20the%20TDZ%20is%3A%20the%20term%20to%20describe%20the%20state%20where%20variables%20are%20un%2Dreachable.%20They%20are%20in%20scope%2C%20but%20they%20aren%27t%20declared.) is the definition:

> TDZ is a term to describe the state when variables are not available.
> They are in scope ***but not declared.***

And here it seems to be that the declaration occurs during the execution of the code, not before execution when context execution is created. So when does it actually happen?

Comment: "*Here is the definition:*" that's not **the** definition. It's just somebody's blog post. Not an authoritative formal normative reference. "not declared" is not technically correct but also an OK term to describe the behaviour. In reality, it doesn't matter *when* it is declared whether `x = 1; let x;` fails because `x` is declared but uninitialised or not declared is irrelevant. The behaviour is the same. The author either tried to simplify "until the line with the declaration is reached" which is a bit of unnecessary detail or just made a mistake. In either case, it hardly matters.

Comment: The text is talking informally. Formally it would be "They are in scope but execution has not yet reached the point of their declaration."